# Pandas Google sheet API - append data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-sheets-api

I wrote a script that takes an excel file and transforms it into a data frame then upload its value to a google sheet. my problem is that I change the **row range** manually and I want it to append to the next row automatically

```
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = r'path'
    API_SERVICE_NAME = 'sheets'
    API_VERSION = 'v4'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    gsheetId = 'id'
    
    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
    
    def Export_Data_To_Sheets():
        
        URL = r'path'
        df = pd.read_excel(URL)
        df.replace(np.nan, '', inplace=True)
    
        response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
            spreadsheetId=gsheetId,
            valueInputOption='RAW',
            range='Raw-Data!A25:N25', //here is what I want to fix
            body=dict(
                majorDimension='ROWS',
                values=df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist())
        ).execute()


Export_Data_To_Sheets()
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, please remove `!A25:N25` from `range='Raw-Data!A25:N25'` as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
range='Raw-Data!A25:N25',
```

To:

```
range='Raw-Data',
```

- By this modification, `values` is appended to the sheet of `Raw-Data`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)